# Cancel sort if certain conditions are met

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I'm using jquery plugin [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) and I'm stuck with the following situation: my grid allow inline edition and if edition is active I want to disallow users to sort columns since this causes troubles.

How can I disallow sorting under certain conditions? I thought event `sortStart` would help me but I have no mechanism in there to cancel the sort.

Comment: Have you tried returning false?  That's pretty standard for cancelling an action.

Comment: @ThinkingSites: yes, I tried that as first shoot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without enough information about your problem, I can say the safest way to go would be to define a flag variable (boolean) which will be set to true when inline editing is in progress, and set to false when editing is finished. Then, you could recode your sorting event to return false if your flag variable is true.

UPDATE

Here is the solution: http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-options-headers.html. You can disable sorting using the code from this example.

Comment: and how I could do that with tablesorter plugin? It provides no mechanism to do that.

Comment: let me check out its docs... while I'm on it, you can check if you can modify its events easily

Comment: return false doesn't cancel the sort unfortunately. That was the first thing I tried.

Comment: I've updated my answer, it relies on the sortDisabled property (not sure how comfortable are you editing the plugin)

Comment: Yeah, it's far from a great solution... But maybe you can find a better plugin/combination of plugins. You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

When you're editing, set `locked` to `true`:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("table").tablesorter(); 
    //assign the sortStart event 
    $("table").bind("sortStart",function() { 
        if(locked) return false;
    }); 
});
```

I'll test this in a min.

Comment: return false doesn't cancel the sort unfortunately. That was the first thing I tried